# Looping Through and Running the Same Method on an Array of Contracts

Tags: web3js, javascript

I am trying to retrieve the price of four contracts all using the same ABI. I have made the array 'Contract' so I can loop through them and apply the same method of "Price":

```
var Contract = [];

Contract.push(TheContractName.at("0x23db685b4f40fc3565ecba26751570e60eed82fd"));
Contract.push(TheContractName.at("0xeefc6f5b60ce3481add637dc661d1f82f4041b56"));
Contract.push(TheContractName.at("0xc7138f91b01660206447e756ccca7ac54a15c4cf"));
Contract.push(TheContractName.at("0xf0a9d6b665e2ce6975cffe4f3b4ffd5abafe5933"));
```

Then I made a loop to fetch the results through Web3.js:

```
Contract.forEach(function(Price) {
    console.log(Price);
});
```

However, this just gives me the results of the original array.

I have used this function to retrieve successfully the price when there is no array involved:

```
Contract.Price(function(error, result) {
     console.log("Price " + result / 1000000000000000000 + " Ether");
});
```

If I can retrieve the results, I will then make a new array for the values returned, and append the data-* fields in the HTML. With this you can then sort the appended divs with the data-* tag values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pushing contracts into an array, but then you're just printing them out instead of calling a method on them. Try this:

```
var contracts = [];

contracts.push(TheContractName.at("0x23db685b4f40fc3565ecba26751570e60eed82fd"));
contracts.push(TheContractName.at("0xeefc6f5b60ce3481add637dc661d1f82f4041b56"));
contracts.push(TheContractName.at("0xc7138f91b01660206447e756ccca7ac54a15c4cf"));
contracts.push(TheContractName.at("0xf0a9d6b665e2ce6975cffe4f3b4ffd5abafe5933"));

contracts.forEach(function (contract) {
    contract.Price(function (error, result) {
        console.log("Price " + result / 10**18 + " ether");
    });
});
```

Comment: This is works, wow. I spent about 8 hours trying to figure that out. I guess the call and response syntax confused me. The good news is I learned the new ways of doing loops in ES 5 and on. 

I'm curious about the use of 10**18, while it is more convenient and easy to read, won't this cost more CPU cycles? I wrote the long form as it is just basic division.

Comment: Something like `web3.fromWei(result, 'ether').toString()` would be even better. Yes, both take a few more CPU cycles, but that's right after doing a _network call_. An extremely premature optimization. :-)